# Variable pane in intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

Once again I closed my variable pane in intelliJ and cant figure out how to re-open it. I asked this question previously but I had an older version on intelliJ, and I am pretty sure it changed because before I used to click a stack looking icon and it worked but now its not there. Does anyone know how to find it in the most recent version?

I tried doing ctrl-shift-a and searched "variable pane" however I didn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been unable to figure out a real solution to this, but I've worked around it by pressing the reset pane button shown by the red arrow: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P9J8.png

Answer (score 0):

In IC 12.x look at screenshot. It will restore only variables pane. [image: Restore variables pane]

Comment: I think there is a bug were that button is missing, but I can't consistently reproduce it.